# Multilevel inheritance with more than three levels

Tags: design-patterns, php

Is many Levels of multilevel inheritance is considered bad?

This is my design

```
BaseFileProcessor
RefundFile Processor inherits BaseFileProcessor (Has n child class)
FailedRefundFile Processor inherits RefundFile (Has n child class)
FailedRefundFile for CardsPayment inherits FailedRefundFile (n child class)
```

Comment: Seems related: https://dev.to/wrongabouteverything/implementation-inheritance-is-evil-3bb

Answer (score 4):

The [yo-yo problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=yo-yo+problem&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS752US752&oq=yo-yo+problem&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is not simply a level counting exercise. Keeping the level number to 1 only makes it impossible to create this particular problem. It is certainly conceivable that four levels of inheritance could exist in a well written, easy to understand, codebase that calls things in a straightforward manner.

The danger is even if that's true it only takes one dopy coder to jump in and start entwining things into a yo-yo mess that sends the reader up and down the inheritance stack.

But no, it entirely misses the point to say "more than three levels is bad". Understand the problem and how to mitigate it.  It's far better to say, "When you use multi level inheritance take a moment and be sure you're not unnecessarily giving your readers motion sickness."

With a little more work you can usually eliminate the need for multi-level inheritance, which can make the code more readable. Good coders are willing to do a little extra work to keep their code readable. But good coders also understand the law of diminishing returns. So it's really a question of how much. Don't fall into the trap of blindly fanatically avoiding this problem. 
 You only end up creating different problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Or, lets say 'currently out of fashion'

The very things that would have in the past made this a 'good' design, ie reuse of the code in the inherited classes is now seen as problematic from a maintenance standpoint.

For example, lets say I fix I bug in your BaseFileProcessor. I will have changed the behaviour of every class with it in its inheritance chain.

If I'm using it as a way to extend my business logic: say I have your failed credit card processor and various Failed{PaymentMethodGoesHere}Processor(s) Then I might have effected 100's of classes and their retrospective business processes.

While this is a 'good' thing for the point of view of code reuse and potentially fixing the bug in those 100 classes with just one change. From a change management perspective its bad.

That bug might have only been reported against a single payment type. Now I have changed a whole load of stuff that was presumably working fine. (Or at least without complaint)

Businesses like to be able to put a limit on the scope of a change. I'm constantly asked 'But that will only affect this... right?'

They would rather you do 100 small changes over time than one big bang change with the same scope.

And for good reason! When you code is a few years old, has been extended by several people and they ask a new hire to 'just fix this small bug', who can really say what the effects will be in all those child classes?

However, I should add a disclaimer. This really applies to 'business logic' which is lets say a bit of an oxymoron.

If you are writing some technical implementation of a well defined spec or maths function, once complete its not going to change and it will be very clear what's a bug and what isn't. Or say you are writing a one off application like a game. Where you wont be coming back to change things post release. These arguments about maintainability and change management don't apply.